# Prestashop image slider shows on desktop but not mobile

Tags: prestashop

I purchased a theme for my prestashop site. It has an imageslider on the homepage, but it doesn't show on mobile. Here is the code for the hook:

/mysite/themes/mytheme/templates/index.tpl

```
{if $page.page_name == 'index'}
{block name='top_column'}
        <div id="top_column" class="">
                {hook h='displayTopColumn'}
         </div>
{/block}
{/if}
```

even though this is editing the module directly which probably shouldn't be done, I thought I could comment out this line so that the image slider would show on mobile, but no luck..

/mysite/modules/ps_imageslider/ps_imageslider.php

```
    // Disable on mobiles and tablets
    //$this->disableDevice(Context::DEVICE_MOBILE);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In admin module manager page: is this module active in mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Module (listings) page...
Click the down arrow to show module options..
& check if the module is disabled by default on mobile!?

[image: Image attached]